# Change the default base class instead of "object"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction

Not sure if it is not logical but want to learn. If we don't declare our base class when creating a new class, both visual studio and compiler knows it inherits "object". is there any way to tell the compiler and visual studio(for intellisense) that my base class is not "object", it is "myobject" for example? maybe any configuration on visual studio?

you can say "inherit all your classes from 'myobject'", i know it but just want to know is it possible.

Answer (score 9):

No, absolutely not. This is part of the C# spec, and is in no way optional. From section 10.1.4.1:

> If a class declaration has no *class-base*, or if the *class-base* lists only interface types, the direct base class is assumed to be `object`.

No implementation-specific wiggle-room - that's just the way it is. Personally I'm glad - I want to be able to tell the direct base class just from looking at the source code, without knowing any project configuration.

EDIT: Just to be clear, C# *could* have been designed such that a different type could be specified as the base type. For example, I could imagine (but dislike) a language where:

```
class Foo
{
}
```

compiled with:

```
csc /evil:DefaultBaseClass=System.IO.Stream Foo.cs
```

was equivalent to:

```
class Foo : Stream
{
}
```

That doesn't break .NET at all - it's a purely language decision. What *is* enforced by .NET is that most types end up with *at least an indirect* base class of `System.Object`. I don't think a language could be designed to allow you to set up a "parallel" type hierarchy.

Comment: Is it a requirement of C#, or of .net in general?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: It's a requirement of .NET that *eventually* the chain would work up to `System.Object` (at least I think it is) but it's up to C# to determine what you mean when you declare a type which doesn't specify a base class. You could easily design your own language which had a different default base class.

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible, the way C# is designed, [(almost)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) everything derives from [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). If this were not the case you couldn't rely on the methods `Object` provides being there, which are pretty fundamental/useful.

Note that it is .Net that requires all objects to be derived from `Object` (directly or indirectly). C# specifies that objects declared with no base class inherit from `Object`, other languages are free to specify another type, however that type must inherit (directly or indirectly) from `Object` as per .net requirements.

Obviously you're free to have your own base class for all types you create, however that base class has to inherit from object (either directly or indirectly).

Do you want to add methods to all/existing types? In which case use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx).

Comment: That in no way forces C# to use `object` as the default. If you had a `class MyClass : Object`, C# *could* allow you to set a default such that a class declaration of `class Foo` would be equivalent to `class Foo : MyClass`. This is a *language* decision - and one which C# *does* enforce, but it *could* be designed differently without .NET itself changing. I'm currently not downvoting, but I think this answer is misleading or misguided.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Edited my post, to hopefully clarify things (unless i'm misunderstanding).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Well, sort of - but your first sentence is still misleading IMO. It's not possible in C# (which is what the question is about) because of the way C# is defined, not because of .NET.

Comment: @George Duckett ".Net that requires all objects to be derived from Object", Does that make any sense if the class you wanted to make default base is derived from object?

Comment: Yeah, obviously .net lets you derive from a class that itself derives from object (either directly, or higher up the inheritance chain).

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the existing item templates (or create a new one) so that new classes automatically inherit from some base class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$ : SomeBaseClass
    {
    }
}
```

See [Customizing Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom abstract class and override the 4 methods defined by the Object class and further add new virtual and abstract methods to your custom base class. Then, you can use this class as the base class explicitly for all your other custom classes. But, that will still mean the super base class of all the classes will be Object only (you can't change that). e.g.

```
//your custom base class
public abstract class MyObject
{
    public virtual void MyCustomMethod()
    {
        //Your custom method implementation
    }

    public abstract void MyCustomAbstractMethod();        

    public override string ToString( )
    {
       //your custom implementation for override
    }

    public override string Equals( )
    {
        //your custom implementation for override
    }

    public override string GetHashCode( )
    {
        //your custom implementation for override
    }

    public override string GetType( )
    {
        //your custom implementation for override
    }
}

//your custom child class
public class CustomClass1 : MyObject //still derived from object
{
    //implement and override the MyObject and object methods
}

//your custom child class
public class CustomClass2 : MyObject //still derived from object
{
    //implement and override the MyObject and object methods
}
```

But all the built-in types provided by the .Net BCL will not be able to use your `MyObject` class, they still will be known to be derived from object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok one thing: In C# and Java all classes declared are derived automatically from Object. There is no changing this. Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Now, you can have your classes inherit another class like:

```
public class A : B // A inherits B
```

but up the chain, you will still find Object at the top because anyway B inherited Object.

Answer (score 0):

i think every thing in .NET inherites from object class. 4 example, becouse it, every object have ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

All the classes and struct inheret from Object, it is the parent of all, even you inherited from a class

```
public class A : B // A inherits B
```